# Custom font with bold

Tags: fonts

Defined a custom font with

```
\font\authfont=cmr10.5 at 10pt
```

Now, I am trying to use it, but make it bold:

```
\author{
%\expandafter\showthe\font
\authfont{
\textbf{

...

}}}
```

However, it is not bold. I have tried switching the composition as well (bold(authfont))

I am preparing this paper for a conference with a large existing stylesheet (emnlp2020.sty), but not sure why such behaviour is not working

Comment: You should _never_ use `\font` in a latex  document. `\font` is the lowest level tex primitive to access a font file and if you use it like this you cut through every layer of latex's font handling. You get what you asked for but LaTex has no idea what you did and no latex font commands for bold or large etc will know about the font.

Comment: in this case there is no font with name `cmr10.5` so `\font` can not work anyway, but you do not say what you are trying to achieve with that definition.  The default font is cmr10 at 10pt so not declaring a font at all is the closest thing that I can suggest.

Comment: Finally `\author` should just have the name and no formatting, journals typically want to extract metadata about titles and author etc and such data should not have tex formating.

Comment: If the conference has provided you a style sheet in the form of a `.sty` package, why are you trying to override it?

Answer (score 1):

The template is publicly available and the sample `.tex` file starts with

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hyperref]{emnlp2020}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\ttfamily\small}

% This is not strictly necessary, and may be commented out,
% but it will improve the layout of the manuscript,
% and will typically save some space.
\usepackage{microtype}

%\aclfinalcopy % Uncomment this line for the final submission
%\def\aclpaperid{***} %  Enter the acl Paper ID here

%\setlength\titlebox{5cm}
% You can expand the titlebox if you need extra space
% to show all the authors. Please do not make the titlebox
% smaller than 5cm (the original size); we will check this
% in the camera-ready version and ask you to change it back.

\newcommand\BibTeX{B\textsc{ib}\TeX}

\title{Instructions for EMNLP 2020 Proceedings}

\author{First Author \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 2 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 3 \\
  \texttt{email@domain} \\\And
  Second Author \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 2 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 3 \\
  \texttt{email@domain} \\}

\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
```

The result will be

[image]

and this is what the conference managers *want*. Don't try to override the standard *they* want.

If I uncomment the `\aclfinalcopy` line, the result is

[image]

The font for the author part is 12pt and is automatically bold for the author name, medium weight for the affiliation, even larger than what you're trying to get and it is Times, as per the instruction `\usepackage{times}`.

Answer (score 0):

`cmr` means roman font, you should use `cmb`

```
\font\authfont=cmb10 at 10pt

\author{%
\authfont%
...
}
```

As you are not providing full `MWE`, I just corrected the error in your code...

Comment: This is surely the wrong answer, the right answer is not to use `\font`. Using that is the source of the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But in `PlainTeX` `\font` is correct...